# RGB interface with MCU

Tags: rgb, tft

I am referring *7" LCD (P/N : S070WV20-CT16)* for interface with host controller LPC1769.

[Datasheet](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/5915d123cd011af01f4c3c41da107221/S070WV20-CT16-INS.pdf)
Part of datasheet I've added here:

[image: LCD datasheet]
[image: LCD datasheet]
[image]

TFT has data pins ( R0-R7,G0-G7,B0-B7), Control pins 
(Mode,DE,DCLK,VS,HS,RESET,DITH), power pins (VCOM,DVDD,VGH,VGL,AVDD)

For power requirement we can use dedicated boost converter to meet up all power requirements (VCOM,DVDD,VGH,VGL,AVDD). For eg.[Link](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=tps65160a&fileType=pdf)

So, my question is,

- For data Pins ( R0-R7,G0-G7,B0-B7) and Control pins 
  (Mode,DE,DCLK,VS,HS,RESET,DITH).. can we assign LPC1769 GPIO pins directly to these pins of TFT?

please someone explain.Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why not. They're just wires...

Comment: Sorry if it's seems too obvious but I was worried whether there is any requirement of RGB converter or so ( i dont know whether such converter exists or not ) before assigning to RGB pins of 7" TFT.

Comment: Have you checked the voltage specs?

Comment: LPC1769 is 3.3V and TFT DVDD pin also 3.3V... So i think voltage logic level will not be issue for Data and control pins... Right?

Comment: The timing for these displays is usually pretty rigid, so it's often best to use a dedicated LCD controller or LCD controller peripheral in a microcontroller.

Comment: Datasheet suggests it has HX8264-D02 TFT source driver with timing controller. Link:http://www.newhavendisplay.com/app_notes/HX8264-D02.pdf  .... so Is it same controller which you are mentioning? If yes, still I need LCD controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can directly interface the pins with your microcontroller, but I don't think it will work. Here's why and why not:

Why:
Electrically, you're hooking up a large number of I/O signals between two devices. As long as these are both at the same voltage (3.3V in this case), you can certainly get data from point A to point B without breaking anything.

Why Not:
However, this is a 24-bit RGB interface which is a large parallel interface. You'll note that you have a clock and some sync signals on the interface as well. Display timing is very important -- you have 800*480 pixels to drive on that display. So to set one pixel, you must setup 24-bits of information on the wires (say you output white pixel, so 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF). Then you must clock in that data / indicate where on the panel that should appear. Then you need to repeat this process 383,999 remaining pixels.

Now, I note that there is no minimum clock frequency specified in the controller datasheet -- if this is just updating a logo every now and then, and it's acceptable to draw it slowly, you could potentially bit-bang that stuff out. But note that the datasheet expects a typical operating frequency of 40MHz -- that's all but impossible to bit-bang out of a microcontroller that has anything else to do.

If you find a processor with a dedicated LCD controller peripheral, it will likely offer a DMA or similar interface where it will take care of clocking data from memory to the display, instead of consuming CPU cycles to meet timing + get the data to the display.